# Plotting two line graphs in 1

Tags: r, plot, graph, ggplot2, timeserieschart

I have a data frame with 3 columns called `x1`, `y1a` and `y1b`. 
`x1` is a date sequence from `2015-01-01` to `2015-04-30`. The columns `y1a` and `y1b` contain values corresponding to each date in `x1`. I want to plot a graph with the line plots of both `y1a` and `y1b` against `x1` and provide labels. 
I tried

```
x1 <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-04-30"), by = "day")
y1a <- rnorm(length(x1))
y1b <- rnorm(length(x1))

plot.co.one <- data.frame(x1, y1a, y1b)

require(ggplot2)

ggplot(plot.co.one, aes(x1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=y1a), colour = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=y1b), colour = "green")
```

but somehow, it does not display the labels.

Comment: Consider adding a small example data set.  Regardless, consider including the error statement you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to map (not set) a colour to a variable, such that it appears in the legend!

Here is some example data set and the plot

```
library(ggplot2)

x1 <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-04-30"), by = "day")
y1a <- rnorm(length(x1))
y1b <- rnorm(length(x1))

plot.co.one <- data.frame(x1, y1a, y1b)

ggplot(plot.co.one, aes(x = x1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = y1a, colour = "Line 1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y1b, colour = "Line 2")) +
  labs(colour = "Timeseries")
```

[image]

### Alternative

As an alternative you can always gather the columns into one and then plot

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

alternative <- plot.co.one %>% 
  rename("Line 1" = y1a, "Line 2" = y1b) %>% 
  gather("Timeseries", "Value", `Line 1`:`Line 2`)

ggplot(alternative, aes(x = x1, y = Value, colour = Timeseries)) + 
  geom_line()
```

This gives identical results (except for the axis labels).

Answer (score -1):

I think R don't recognize Date_2015 as class "Date".
If you change " x1 <- Date_2015 " into " x1 <- as.Date(Date_2015) ", maybe it'll work.

[Edit] Sorry, I couldn't understand your question.

```
library(ggplot2); library(tidyr)

# Using Mr. Manuel's code, thanks.
x1 <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-04-30"), by = "day")
y1a <- rnorm(length(x1))
y1b <- rnorm(length(x1))
plot.co.one <- data.frame(x1, y1a, y1b)

# "key" becomes a col name, and a legend title. Value also becomes col name and ylab.
plot.co.one2 <- gather(plot.co.one, key="y1_ab", value = y1, -x1)
ggplot(plot.co.one2, aes(x = x1, y = y1, colour = y1_ab)) + geom_line() + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "green"))
```

[image: plot]